# How to use chart.js in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, chart.js

Surprisingly, despite chart.js being so popular, I didn't found neither documentation about its installation in angular2, neither a simple example of its usage there.

If in case usage in angular2 [example here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-usage) will be enough to understand, I can't say the same about simple install.

I have installed chart.js using

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

Next, I'm trying to import it with

```
import Chart from 'chart.js';
```

Immediately a problem - `TS2307: Cannot find module 'chart.js'`
It supposed to be simple, but module isn't even recognized after installation.

I guess, having point in name is a bad thing, but is there a way to pass through it (using Gruntfile.js maybe)?

P.S I saw examples with `ng2-charts` and I considering to use it, but as I understand, it still requires chart.js + I don't know if it allows to create mix charts (didn't saw any example yet)

Comment: Did you `npm install --save @types/chart.js`?

Comment: No, I did exactly as I writted in the question (or here http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-installation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using TypeScript you just need to install the @types package

```
npm install --save chart.js @types/chart.js
```

now TypeScript knows how to typecheck use of the package and the following will work.

```
import Chart = require('chart.js'); // For CommonJS users.

import Chart from 'chart.js'; // for SystemJS and/or Babel users.

const myChart = new Chart($('#chart1'), {});
```

Note, I show two imports in the example above. Remove whichever does not work at *runtime* but only keep one of them.

For SystemJS + npm, add the following to the `map` section of your systemjs.config.js

```
"chart.js": "npm:chart.js/dist/chart.js"
```

Optionally, if and only if you are using the ng2-charts wrapper, then run

```
npm install --save ng2-charts
```

And then add it you your primary `NgModule` decorator factory's, `imports` array

```
import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ChartsModule
  ]
}) export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Hm... interesting... I will try it. Well, already can say that `import Chart from 'chart.js';` not working because `@types/chart.js/index has no default export`, will try another one.

Comment: @OlegsJasjko SystemJS/Babel provide a synthetic `default` which TypeScript can be told about using `--allowSynetheticDefaultImports` but don't do that unless it works at runtime. If it doesn't work use `import ... = require(...)`

Comment: Now i got this beauty `Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/chart.js`... hm...

Comment: npm (mentioned in the question)

Comment: You need to add it to your `systemjs.config.js` file's `map` configuration. `"map": { "chart.js": "npm:chart.js/src/chart.js" }` also you want to use the _first_ import form with SystemJS

Comment: Does I also need to update packages and add there something like this `'chart.js': { defaultExtension: 'js' }`?

Comment: That's likely since `"chart.js/src/chart.js"` is a module which imports other files and not a bundle. Look at the structure of the installed package folder. There is probably a single bundled file you can point at in which case you don't need to add the `packages` config.

Comment: And its still not working, because now it tries to get everything. For example `GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/chart.js/src/core/core.helpers 404 (Not Found)`. Is it `src/chart.js`, or maybe it must be `dist/Chart.js`?

Comment: Just just use that or set defaultExtension like you said. If you're using rollup optimizations with the SystemJS Builder you'll want to use the package

Comment: Worked only with dist/Chart.js .... package changes didn't helped at all. Thanks for your effort and wow... I just don't believe that nobody ever get those kind of problems at all (considering almost not existent info on this term)

Comment: @OlegsJasjko, glad you got it working. I see that you mention npm in your question as you stated, but in future questions stating which loader or bundler you use will speed up the answering process. I would have asked for your _system.config.js_ file as well and my `import` advice would have been very specific. Anyway, cheers!

Comment: Updated answer based on your experience

Comment: what about Webpack ? How can it be used?

Comment: I imagine you don't need to do anything if you are using a recent version of Webpack. It should work after you install the package.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple to use in angular2...

1. Installation :

   ```
   npm install angular2-chartjs
   ```
2. Add ChartModule to your module :

   ```
   import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-chartjs';
   @NgModule({
     imports: [ ChartModule ]
   })

   export class AppModule {
   }
   ```
3. JavaScript

   ```
   type = 'line';
   data = {
     labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
     datasets: [{
       label: "My First dataset",
       data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
     }]
   };
   options = {
     responsive: true,
     maintainAspectRatio: false
   };
   ```
4. HTML

   ```
   <chart [type]="type" [data]="data" [options]="options"></chart>
   ```

Link: https://github.com/emn178/angular2-chartjs "Documentation"

Enjoy Happy codeing. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: How can you do a `.update()` like this? As the official documentation sais? http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Answer (score 1):

For an Angular CLI project, you'd want to add the `chart.js` dependency in the `.angular-cli.json` in the `scripts` array property like this:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"
]
```

Otherwise you can import the library using syntax as follows:

`import * as Chart from 'chart.js'`

That being said, I'd recommend using a library such as the one your suggested as you're going to have access to components, directives, and emitted events that will be easier to work with in your components.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Hm, so its really much simpler to use ng2-charts and don't screw my own brains, but does free libraries support mix charts? (so far I only found that is is supported in highchart, but it is not a free one)

Comment: The charts that are currently supported by ng2-charts are line, bar, radar, pie, polarArea, and doughnut. That being said, you can try your hand at extending the extending the ng2-charts source. The mix charts will use effectively the same inputs.

Comment: Yeah I know, I mean, does it allow to combine those? Like line+bar for example? The reason I even decided to use chart.js Is because it allows those things.

Comment: That will load it as a global. This is not needed. Since you are using modules and chart.js is well behaved you are unnecessarily writing bad code.'

Answer (score 0):

Change your import syntaxt to this :

```
import Chart from "chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js";
```

make sure you already did

```
npm install chart.js --save
```

if youalready did, in you node modules supposed to have nodemodules/chart.js

Answer (score -1):

Simple workaround is to add this to index.html:

```
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

I actually use PrimeNG which have a charts component based on chart.js, also had issues. This was the quickest way to get up and running. Make sure you reference the 'bundle' package.

Comment: Don't do that. It is not portable and it pollutes the global object. If you are using a module loader/bundler, then do not use global variables if you do not need to, that is the point of modules.